# Can't write copy of activity in newly created databases

Tags: brightway

I am trying to write a copy of an activity from an existing database (in this case `ecoinvent 3.2 cut-off`, but that shouldn't matter) into a new database. I have:

```
In:  ei = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff')
     testDB = bw.Database('testdb')
     testDB.register()
     bw.databases
Out: Brightway2 databases metadata with 3 objects:
         biosphere3
         ecoinvent 3.2 cutoff
         testdb

In:  act = ei.random()
     actCopy = act.copy()
     testDB.write(actCopy)
Out: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
     WrongDatabase                             Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-20-831953ab6cb9> in <module>()
     ----> 1 testdb.write(act)
     [...]
     WrongDatabase: Can't write activities in databases {'a', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'r', 'n', 'f', 'l', 't', 'p'} to database testdb
```

What is the meaning of the single letter strings in the set in the error message?

What part of my code makes the writing to my new database break down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Database('foo').write(data)` requires that `data` is a dictionary, see the [technical documentation](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/technical/bw2data.html#bw2data.backends.peewee.database.SQLiteBackend.write). In this case, `actCopy` is an activity proxy, so the easiest solution would be to use `actCopy.save()`. Alternatively, you could use the following utility function to get a list of activities into the correct form:

```
def format_me(list_of_activities, database_obj):
    return {(database_obj.name, obj['code']): obj for obj in list_of_activities}
```

The reason you get the error message "`Can't write activities in databases {'a', 'd', 'u', 'c', 'r', 'n', 'f', 'l', 't', 'p'} to database testdb`" is that you are passing a list, and one of the things the `write` function does is to make sure that you are *not* trying to write data to the wrong database. The way it does this is to iterate over the keys in the dictionary `data`, and take the first element as the database name. It then checks to make sure that these names are same as the database which is being written to. When you passed a data object like this:

```
{
    'alpha': 'something',
    'delta': 'something',
    'umberto': 'something',
    'california': 'something',
    ...
}
```

Then, when iterating over the object you passed into `data`, it would get these database keys, i.e. `alpha`, `delta`, etc. It then takes the first element (`a`, `d`, etc.) and checks to make sure the database name is correct

Here is the [actual `bw2data` code](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/8d15f74ea7980de4825429a2814dd6f7501aa25a/bw2data/backends/peewee/database.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#database.py-216) that raises this error:

```
wrong_database = {key[0] for key in data}.difference({self.name})
if wrong_database:
    raise WrongDatabase("Can't write activities in databases {} to database {}".format(
                        wrong_database, self.name))
```

Comment: Wonderful, very clear. I checked, and indeed the letters in the set {'a', 'd', etc.} are the first letters of the keys of the activity as a database, obtained by `set([key[0] for key in act.as_dict().keys()])` (I just needed to convince myself).

Comment: where exactly does actCopy.save() actually save the activity? I am using the SQL backend, have created a copy of an activity, modified its name and code, and `save()`d it. It doesn't show up in the search of the database. How can I get it there (without rewriting the whole database)?

Comment: Filed as a bug report here: https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/issues/44/copying-an-activity-and-then-saving-doesnt. Would be nice to get an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).